# Bind dropdownlist value from enum value with custom sequence

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums, dropdown

I am using visual studio 2013 and bind asp.net drop down control from Enum value

I have this enum.

```
enum Name
    {
        Kumar = 1,
        Raju = 2,
        Anil = 3,
        Suresh = 4,
        Bhaskar = 5,            
    };
```

Now i have add one more value in enum **Chandra = 6** , but i want that **Bhaskar = 5**  should be in last position when i bind drop downlist and cannot update the enum sequence.

I want this type result in dropdownlist.

```
 Kumar 
 Raju 
 Anil  
 Suresh 
 Chandra
 Bhaskar
```

This is how I currently populate the dropdown :

```
Array itemValues = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(Name)); 
Array itemNames = System.Enum.GetNames(typeof(Name)); 
for (int i = 0; i <= itemNames.Length - 1 ; i++) 
{ 
    ListItem item = new ListItem(itemNames[i], itemValues[i]); 
    dropdownlist.Items.Add(item); 
}
```

Comment: How do you bind the enum values currently?

Comment: `Array itemValues = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(Name));
Array itemNames = System.Enum.GetNames(typeof(Name));

for (int i = 0; i <= itemNames.Length - 1 ; i++) {
    ListItem item = new ListItem(itemNames[i], itemValues[i]);
    dropdownlist.Items.Add(item);
}`

Comment: In the future, please don't post code snippet in comment again ([edit] your question instead). It is practically unreadable. Please, make it easy for others to help you (I had to manually format your code to be able to understand it. And I won't be doing this often!). Thanks

Comment: Okay, I will consider this point in further question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a custom ordering using LINQ `OrderBy()` as follow :

```
var itemNames = System.Enum.GetNames(typeof(Name)).OrderBy(o => o == "Bhaskar" ? 1 : 0);
```

This way `'Bhaskar'` should be the last item in the `itemNames` and other enum values ordered as they are in the enum definition.

**Demo :** (see it live in [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DTXryv))

```
enum Name
{
    Kumar = 1,
    Raju = 2,
    Anil = 3,
    Suresh = 4,
    Bhaskar = 5,
    Chandra = 6
};

public static void Main()
{
    var itemNames = System.Enum.GetNames(typeof(Name))
                               .OrderBy(o => (string)o == "Bhaskar" ? 1 : 0)
                               .ToArray(); 
    for (int i = 0; i <= itemNames.Length - 1 ; i++) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine((string)itemNames[i]);
    }
}
```

**output :**

```
Kumar
Raju
Anil
Suresh
Chandra
Bhaskar
```

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much, This code is proper working for me.